# MVC Performance: Setting view name vs leaving it blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been wondering would it be more performance wise to define the view name in controller's APIs than allowing MVC to automatically find them?

For example

```
public ActionResult Test() { return View("Test"); }
public ActionResult Test() { return View(); }
```

Asking this question because I think when the name is not set, ASP.Net MVC has to make some search (not sure if it uses indexing on available pages) as well using reflections to determine the API's name and try to find a matching view. But the hardcoded case just tells the complier what to fetch. So, just wanna make sure to what extent this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real performance penalty involved because when no view name provided, the framework extracts it from the current `RouteData` (that is already available and instantiated - no Reflection involved).

From [source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewResultBase.cs#L82):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName))
    ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes by convention, there isn't any performance to be gained by this... MVC will look for `<ControllerName>\<ActionName>.cshtml` (thats the convention).

If you're looking for performance gains, look at bundling you CSS/JS files, caching policies, optimizing images and using AJAX + WebAPI